# Repeater binding issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have an issue with **Repeater binding** and I get this message:

> DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name
>   'CotisationMensuelle'.

This is the C# code:

```
XDocument docxx = XDocument.Parse(Session["xmlrs" + z + ""].ToString());
//This now holds the set of all elements named field

try
{
    XNamespace foobar = "http://www.april-technologies.com";
    var urlList = docxx.Descendants(foobar + "CotisationMensuelle")
                       .Select(x => (string)x)
                       .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(urlList);

    rpMyRepeater1.DataSource = urlList;
    rpMyRepeater1.DataBind();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

The aspx page code:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CotisationMensuelle") %>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: need to see how your aspx page repeater markup look like, can you update the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have aspx page markup for repeater something like below

```
<asp:Repeater ID ="rpMyRepeater1" ItemType="System.string" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <%=this.GetDataItem().ToString() %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

as per your new update if you need to bind as below

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CotisationMensuelle") %>
```

you need to have property called `CotisationMensuelle` , but currently you don't have such , try below

```
  var urlList = docxx.Descendants(foobar + "CotisationMensuelle")
                       .Select(x => new { CotisationMensuelle =(string)x})
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: i HAVE A QUESTION , exemple  urlList return ` 5998 7510 8144 9458 10916 13214 ` and this  return must be  ` 59,98 75,10 81,44 94,58 109,16 132,14 ` How can i adding `,` after 2 number from right ?